# Flutter 2 Renders Images Pixelated

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter2.0

Flutter 2 was released today and I've just upgraded the stable channel in Flutter for a test project. Images are immediately rendered pixelated/low-res. I imagine it has something to do with CanvasKit. Has anyone any idea of how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: It would be a better idea to make a github issue rather than ask here. This seems like a bug report.

Comment: Same issue here, please let me know if you manage to resolve or if this is indeed a bug

Answer (score 0):

First check if the image is stretched bigger than its original size.
If the image is taking its original size this is probably caused by a bug.